# Issue with TF-IDF vector creation in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement TF-IDF using Java referring Spark Scala implementation given in the following link:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala

Until the tokenization step, the code works fine. However, Spark execution (Spark-submit) halts in PairFlatMap function.

I have given my code below:

```
public class tf {

static SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TF IDF Example");
static JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println();
    preprocess();
    System.out.println();
}

private static final Function<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<Long,List<String>>> TOKENIZER =
      new Function<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<Long,List<String>>>() {

        public Tuple2<Long, List<String>> call(Tuple2<String, Long> arg0)
                throws Exception {
            List<String> tokenizedDoc = SimpleTokenizer.getWords(arg0._1());

            return new Tuple2<Long, List<String>>(arg0._2,tokenizedDoc);
        }
      };

      private static final PairFunction<String, String, Integer> WORDS_MAP_ONE = 
              new PairFunction<String, String, Integer> () {

                public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String arg0)
                        throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(arg0, 1);
                }
              };

    private static final PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Long,List<String>>,String, Integer> WORDS_MAP =
          new PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Long,List<String>>,String, Integer>() {

            public Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> call(Tuple2<Long, List<String>> arg0) throws Exception 
            {
                JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> arg1 =  sc.parallelize(arg0._2).mapToPair(WORDS_MAP_ONE);
                return arg1.collect();
            }
            }
          ;

        private static final Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> WORDS_COUNT = 
                new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

                    public Integer call(Integer arg0, Integer arg1)
                            throws Exception {

                        return arg0 + arg1;
                    }
        };

public static void preprocess(){

    String path = "tfidfinput.txt";
    JavaRDD<String> textRDD = sc.textFile(path);

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Long, List<String>>> tokenized = textRDD.zipWithIndex().map(TOKENIZER);
    tokenized.cache();

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> wordCountsDupt = tokenized.flatMapToPair(WORDS_MAP);
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> wordCounts = wordCountsDupt.reduceByKey(WORDS_COUNT);


}
```

Can someone please tell me if there is anything wrong in this implementation?

Comment: actually there is no error as such. Spark-submit execution halts and will not proceed on to anything.